# Copy data from DynamoDB into Redshift across two different AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, aws-redshift

For reasons beyond my control, I have the following:

- A table `CustomerPhoneNumber` in DynamoDB under one AWS account.
- A Redshift cluster under a *different* AWS account (same geographic region; EU)

Is there any way to run the `COPY` command to move data from Dynamo into Redshift across accounts?

Typically if they were under the *same* account, it would be done via `IAM` role pretty easily:

```
copy public.my_table (col1, col2, col3) from 'dynamodb://CustomerPhoneNumber' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/RandomRoleName' readratio 40;
```

But obviously this doesn't work in my case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Answer above by John is not applicable any more; This is how you can do it-

1. AWS account with required resource like dynamodb in this case(trustING account) need to have account requiring access(trusTED AWS account)... as trusted in their Dynamo db read only role: arn:aws:iam:::role/
2. Create a policy which does sts:AssumeRole (above trustING account's role arn as the resource),
3. attach that policy to redshift-access-role(which has all privileges required to run the copy command).
4. Run the command as:

   ```
   iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<trusTEDawsAccountId>:role/redshift_access_role,arn:aws:iam::<trusTINGawsAccountId>:role/<dynamodbreadrole>' 
   readratio 50
   ```

Details in:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/authorizing-redshift-service.html

Comment: This worked, and could be accepted as the right answer. Followed [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-s3-cross-account/) guide for setting up cross-account access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CREDENTIALS and specify the access key and secret key for the other account. Add the following to your COPY statement:

```
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=AKIAXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=yyyyyy'
```

You cannot use cross account roles with Redshift. To quote Amazon documentation:

> An IAM role can be associated with an Amazon Redshift cluster only if
>   both the IAM role and the cluster are owned by the same AWS account.

[Authorizing COPY and UNLOAD Operations Using IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/copy-unload-iam-role.html)

Answer (score -1):

apparently stackoverflow need formatting, the code is:

```
copy redshift_tbl from 'dynamodb://dynamotbl'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<TRUSTEDacAWSid>:role/redshift_access_role,arn:aws:iam::<trusTINGacAWSid>:role/<dynamodb-role-in-trustingac>' 
readratio 50
```

*Note: no space between commas in roles

Comment: Please edit your original answer, instead of posting another one with a correction. I have edited your original answer for you. I recommend you delete this one.